# What features are available in Windows 8 Single Language?

Tags: windows-8

I am purchasing a laptop for home use, and most laptops that I see in my price range come with Windows 8 Single Language Edition.

I'm trying to find a feature matrix which will tell me what all features I get in this edition, and which features are missing when compared to the Windows 8 Pro Edition.

I have not be able to find an authoritative source for these details. Can you please point me to some documentation which details this information?

Comment: Does this help? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_8_editions. Also, I don't think Single Language is an edition?

Comment: @DaveRook That just mentions the Single Language edition in passing, and does not provide any details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Single Language Edition has the same features like the `Core/Basic edition`. The only difference is that only 1 language can be used. [By default MS now allows all editions](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/b8/archive/2012/02/21/using-the-language-you-want.aspx) (this is changed compared to Vista/7) to change the display language.

```
<sl:policyInt name="Kernel-MUI-Number-Allowed" attributes="reboot-required, override-only">1</sl:policyInt>
```

The return code of [GetProductInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724358%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on the Single Edition is **PRODUCT_*CORE*_SINGLELANGUAGE**, this also shows that it is the Core edition.

Comment: Can you please provide a source for this information?

Comment: I posted a link to the Win32 API call. I took the sl:policyInt value from a Single Language Image and compared the license values with the normal Core.

Comment: So, If I understand you correctly, you have actually run the code yourself? If so, that's great.

Comment: yes, I used the code in a test app to show the correct Windows version: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5749744/Bilder/superuser/CoreSingleLanguage_winver.png

Answer (score 2):

According to my research it is Windows 8 only. [This article](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-windows_install/windows-8-single-language-license-upgrade/f5468573-c0dc-4fed-984d-0202d168422a), although not explicit, does seem to confirm this.

Additional: the Single Language (also referred to as SL) was designed to help reduce piracy, spurred on by the level of piracy in China although aimed at 'emerging markets' but only allowing 1 language to be used (and no ability add other languages) but reducing the price of the OS. This would obviously make shipping to other languages more difficult.

Comment: Your research is correct. I found a Volume Licensing Guide For Partners document. Within the document it describes **"Local language-only edition of Windows 8 (Windows 8 Single Language) will be available in select emerging markets."** which is an * description on `Windows 8 Core`. Its not clear if there is any upgrade to `Windows 8 Professional` or `Windows 8 Professional with Media Center`.  Here is the document I discovered https%253a%252f%252fpartner.microsoft.com%252fdownload%252fglobal%252f40188813&id=42377

Answer (score 1):

Windows 8 single language will not have the Hyper-V package, which is only available in Windows 8 Pro and Enterprise Editions. Hyper-V can be used for Windows Phone 8 app development, i.e. running the Windows Phone emulator. It can also be used for virtualization and a lot of other stuff.